# sum a column using multiple criteria between two google sheets

Tags: arrays, sum

I have two sheets:

Sheet A - 4 columns: A,B,C,D
Sheet B - 3 columns: A,B,C

I want to sum the col B from sheet A and put it to column B in sheet B.

**Criteria**

1. The column A from sheet A matches column A from sheet B
2. From sheet A the column C="x" and column D="y"

Then I want to sum the col B from sheet A.and put it to column C in sheet B.

**Criteria**

1. The column A from sheet A matches column A from sheet B
2. From sheet A the column C<>"x"

See link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qdxuSedmA-SO2oN6RC2qBnnbVuG5Io_b_CLSoRub-CM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @shahed mahmoudi . Did you try my link ??

Answer (score 0):

this [Link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/08/excel-reference-another-sheet-workbook/) is useful for solve this problem you should use

> Sheet_name!Cell_address

Comment: I think that you haven't understand what I want to be solved. I dont want to link to another sheet , I want to sum something with multiple criteria between two sheets

Comment: Ops.. yes I didn't understand.but it's esay. can you give me access to solve it?
I will send you request to edit access

Comment: Thank you very much! here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qdxuSedmA-SO2oN6RC2qBnnbVuG5Io_b_CLSoRub-CM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think its ok now!!

Comment: Is anyone can give an answer to my question .? I ll appreciate it, because its important to me

Comment: Did you try my link ??